# Fetch message details in Spring RecoveryCallback

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-retry, spring-integration-amqp

I'm publishing messages into RabbitMQ and I would like to track the errors when RabbitMQ is down, for this I added one `RetryTemplate` with the recovery callback, but the recovery callback only provides this method `getLastThrowable()` and I'm not sure how to provide the details of the messages that failed when RabbitMQ is down. (as per documentation "The `RecoveryCallback` is somewhat limited in that the retry context only contains the
`lastThrowable` field. For more sophisticated use cases, you should use an external
`RetryTemplate` so that you can convey additional information to the `RecoveryCallback` via
the context’s attributes") but I don't know how to do that, if anyone could help me with one example that will be awesome.

Rabbit Template

```
public RabbitTemplate rabbitMqTemplate(RecoveryCallback publisherRecoveryCallback) {
    RabbitTemplate r = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    r.setExchange(exchangeName);
    r.setRoutingKey(routingKey);
    r.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    r.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(10.0);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    r.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    r.setRecoveryCallback(publisherRecoveryCallback);
    return r;
    }
```

Recovery Callback

```
@Component
public class PublisherRecoveryCallback implements RecoveryCallback<AssortmentEvent> {
    @Override
    public AssortmentEvent recover(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
        log.error("Error publising event",context.getLastThrowable());
        //how to get message details here??
        return null;
    }
}
```

AMQP Outbound Adapter

`return IntegrationFlows.from("eventsChannel")
                .split()
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitMqTemplate)
                        .exchangeName(exchangeName)
                        .confirmCorrelationExpression("payload")
                        .confirmAckChannel(ackChannel)
                        .confirmNackChannel(nackChannel)
                )
                .get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isn't possible because the function `RabbitTemplate.execute()` is already not aware about message you send, because it may be performed from any other method, where we might not have messages to deal:

```
return this.retryTemplate.execute(
                    (RetryCallback<T, Exception>) context -> RabbitTemplate.this.doExecute(action, connectionFactory),
                    (RecoveryCallback<T>) this.recoveryCallback);
```

What I suggest you to do is like storing message to the `ThreadLocal` before send and get it from there from your custom `RecoveryCallback`.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using spring integration DSL and I don't have the control of the rabbitTemplate.

Comment: So, you can use `.handle()` to store value into the `ThreadLocal` and return it for the next `.handle(Amqp.outboundChannelAdapter())`

Comment: perfect, I will try to store the message(thread local) in the first handle() and then pass that value to the outbound adatper and then delete that message from the thread local once I received the ack, thank you Artem!!!!!!!